# Why java static variable is not updating?

Tags: java, static

I have a Class called Color in which there are three static Objects (instantiating with the same class itself) and a int type (called i) variable. When I Run the Class, the 'i' variable is increments in the Constructor, but it is not persisting in memory , please explain this below code

```
package test;
public class Color
{
     public static  Color RED = new Color();
     public static final Color BLUE = new Color();
     public static final Color GREEN = new Color();
     static int i=0;

     Color(){
         System.out.println("Incrementing 'i'  here  "+(++i));
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("The 'i' variable is not incremented here, it still shows '0' ,  'i' is: "+ Color.i );  // line 14 
        Color x = new Color();
        System.out.println(x.i);
    }
}
```

The out is as follow:

```
Incrementing 'i'  here  1
Incrementing 'i'  here  2
Incrementing 'i'  here  3
The 'i' variable is not incremented here, it still shows '0' ,  'i' is: 0
Incrementing 'i'  here  1
1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a class is loaded and linked, its `static` fields are all initialized to their default values. Once that is done, the static field initializers are executed in the order they appear in the file, thus completing the initialization of the class. All this happens before any code defined in that class executes. So what's happening here is:

1. `RED`, `GREEN`, `BLUE`, and `i` are initialized to their default values (`null` for the `Color` fields and 0 for `i`). Note that this is independent of any initializers.
2. The initializer for field `RED` (`RED = new Color()`) executes. As a side effect, `i` is incremented to 1.
3. The initializer for field `BLUE` executes and `i` is incremented to 2.
4. The initializer for field `GREEN` executes and `i` is incremented to 3.
5. The initializer for the `static` field `i` executes and `i` is assigned the value 0.
6. The `main()` method executes and produces the results consistent with `i` being 0 when `main()` begins execution.

You can read the gory details of all this in [Chapter 12 of the Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) and [Chapter 5 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-5.html).

You can get the output you expected simply by move the declaration of `i` to be ahead of the `Color` fields:

```
 static int i=0;
 public static  Color RED = new Color();
 public static final Color BLUE = new Color();
 public static final Color GREEN = new Color();
```

Then the output will be:

> Incrementing 'i'  here  1
>   Incrementing 'i'  here  2
>   Incrementing 'i'  here  3
>   The 'i' variable is not incremented here, it still shows '0' ,  'i' is: 3
>   Incrementing 'i'  here  4
>   4

Note that the `final` modifiers have no effect on the order of initialization here because `GREEN` and `BLUE` are not "constant variables" according to the definition of that term in the JLS. A *constant variable* (an unfortunate pairing of words) is a primitive or `String` variable that is both declared `final` and initialized to a constant expression. In this case, `new Color()` is not a constant expression and `Color` is not an appropriate type for a constant variable. See, for instance, [§4.12.4 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

Comment: Speaking of chapter 12 of the JLS, if I'm reading 12.4.1 correctly, won't `BLUE` and `GREEN` be initialized before `RED` because they're `final`?

Comment: @Powerlord no, final doesn't make a constant. Only Strings and primitives can be constants, and there are rules to be respected for that. Besides, constants are initialized like all other fields, it's just that their value can be used before they were initialized, because it was already known at compile time so the compiler replaced the variable access with its known value.

Comment: @Powerlord - You're right. I hadn't noticed the `final` modifier on those two fields. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @kumesana - That analysis is wrong. When the class is first loaded, all static fields (including `final` fields) are initialized to their default values. The compiler doesn't know the address of the object that will be returned by `new Color()`; that is determined when the initializer executes, which happens at run time, later in the initialization process for the class (but still before `main()` begins execution).

Comment: @TedHopp final or non-final doesn't matter and doesn't change the order of initialization. Now that your answer pretends it does, your answer has become incorrect. You could just simply give it a try, by the way. I don't know where that idea started from, but I supposed that it came from the existence of constants, which is an overlapping, but different, subject.

Comment: @kumesana - You're absolutely right. The `final` modifier affects the order of initialization for primitive and `String` fields, so that's probably where the idea started. I've rewritten my answer (again) to remove the incorrect information.

Comment: That's not how it works. You're thinking of constants, and final doesn't make a constant. It's necessary, but not enough. And it's not a matter of order of initialization. It's just that the value of a constant is known at compile time, so it's not necessary to wait for its initialization. Any access to the constant is replaced, by the compiler, with this constant's value. Making the question of the initialization, completely irrelevant. If you still observe with reflection on the field, when it is initialized, well it respects the same rules as the others.

Comment: @kumesana - Then please explain why, in [§12.4.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), step 6 of the initialization procedure says to mark initialization as being in progress and "Then, initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables." Perhaps you're thinking of how the compiler replaces *references* to constant fields with the constant values. The constant fields still exist and need to be initialized because they may be referenced by code that may not even be written yet.

Comment: @Powerlord - I need to correct my earlier response. The `final` modifier does not affect the order of initialization here. It only affects initialization order for so-called "constant variable" fields -- fields that are either of primitive or String type and are initialized to compile-time constants.

Comment: I stand corrected. You're right, the constants' fields are initialized first during class loading. This is yet another special treatment reserved to static constants, when doing class initialization. When the constant field is not static, there is no equivalent mechanism to initialize it first, but then again there is no opportunity to since it's not static and therefore uncorrelated to class initialization. For some reason I thought that there was no such special treatment of static constants during class initialization, and I was wrong. Which can be tested too.

Answer (score 0):

Class Initialization proceeds  top to bottom .When we initialize Color we create a new Color .In order to create a new Color we also have to initialize Color. That's called recursive initialization and what the system does is simply ignores the recursive initialization and executes `new Color()`. This class initializer executes by the below sequence top  to bottom

1. `public static  Color RED = new Color();` this sets static variable i to 1.
2. `public static final Color BLUE = new Color();` this increments static variable i to 2
3. `public static final Color GREEN = new Color();` this increments static variable i to 3
4. `static int i=0;` this sets static variable i back to zero.

Now when the main thread runs.It sees the static variable to 0 and increments to 1.

As a counter example try replacing `static int i=0` to `static Integer i=new Integer(0).` . This will throw a `NullPointerException` . This is because at class initialization time when `public static  Color RED = new Color();` executes  it sees the i as null , because i has not been initialized by then,  resulting in `NullPointerException`